# Number of Rational Solutions $\mathbf{x}\in[0,1)^n$ to the Matrix Condition $\mathbf{A}\,\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{Z}^n$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, matrix-equations, rational-numbers, combinatorial-geometry

> Let $n$ be a positive integer and $\mathbf{A}$ an $n$-by-$n$ matrix with integer entries.  Suppose that $k:=\big|\det(\mathbf{A})\big|$ is nonzero.  How many $n$-by-$1$ column vectors $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{Q}^n$ each of whose entries lies within the interval $[0,1)$ are there with the property that $\mathbf{A}\,\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$ for some $n$-by-$1$ column vector $\mathbf{b}\in\mathbb{Z}^n$?

When $n=1$, the answer is trivially $k$.  According to [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1860642/prove-that-there-are-exactly-k-pairs-x-y-of-rational-numbers-with-0-leq-x), when $n=2$, the answer is also $k$.  I believe that, in general, the answer is $k$.  Geometrically, the image of $\mathbf{x}\mapsto \mathbf{A}\,\mathbf{x}$ for $\mathbf{x}\in[0,1)^n$ is an $n$-dimensional hyper-parallelipiped $H\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ with integral vertices and with volume $k$.  <strike>However, I am not certain how to calculate the number of integral points inside and on the boundary of $H$.  I remember that there may be a theorem relating the volume and the number of integral points within and on the boundary of a convex polytope whose vertices are integral points.  What I do not remember is the name of the theorem and what it states exactly.</strike>

I found out what I was referring to, and it was the [Ehrhart Polynomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrhart_polynomial).  The answer is indeed $k$.  However, I will still greatly appreciate a number-theoretic or algebraic solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are basically asking for the number of (standard) lattice points inside the fundamental parallelepiped $F$ of the lattice generated by the matrix $A$. Since the vertices of $F$ are on the standard lattice, the number of lattice points in $F$ is the same as the number of points in $F+x$ for any translate of $F$ by an integer vector $x$. Therefore, if you multiply (scale) $F$ by an integer $r$, then the number of points in $rF$ is $r^n$ times the number of points in $F$.

On the other hand, for any convex body $K\subset \mathbb{R}^n$,
$$ \lim_{r\to\infty} \frac{\#\{ rK \cap \mathbb{Z}^n \}}{r^n} = \rm{Vol}(K).$$